# Using sphinx/miktex to generate pdf files that displays UTF8 Japanese (CJK) text in windows

Tags: python, windows, pdflatex, python-sphinx, miktex

I have documentation in ReSt (UTF8) and I'm using [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to generate HTML and latex files.
(No issues with html conversion)

I then want to convert the resulting latex file to PDf.  Currently I'm using [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)
 2.7's pdflatex.exe command to perfom this conversion. (Converting a source file without Japanese characters produces the expected pdf correctly)

Using the MiKTeX Package Manager I've installed the cjk related packages: cjk-fonts, miktex-cjkutils-bin-2.7, and cjk.

To debug I'm using the following sample:

```
﻿\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{song}

\noindent Hello World!

\noindent Καλημέρα κόσμε
\noindent こんにちは 世界

\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

Running pdflatex.exe on this file produces the following output:

```
pdflatex jutf8.tex jutf8.pdf
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.8-beta-20080627 (MiKTeX 2.7)
entering extended mode
(jutf8.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8j> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman, ngerman, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, french, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.2
     ｻｿ\documentclass{article}
?
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\base\size10.clo")
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--284
[]
[1{D:/Profiles/All Users/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.7/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\CJK.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\mule\MULEenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\CJK.enc")) (jutf8.aux)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\UTF8.bdg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\UTF8.enc")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\UTF8.chr")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\tex\latex\cjk\UTF8\c70song.fd")Running makemf...
makemf: The cyberb source file could not be found.
Running hbf2gf...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.7.0)

Couldn't find `cyberb.cfg'
maketfm: No creation rule for font cyberb03.

! Font C70/song/m/n/10/03=cyberb03 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file no
t found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.12 \noindent ﾎ
                 ﾎｱﾎｻﾎｷﾎｼﾎｭﾏ∃ｱ ﾎｺﾏ狐πｼﾎｵ
```

How can I get Japanese to display properly in the resulting pdf using MiKTeX/pdflatex.exe?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with miktex, after much investigation found that win32-ptex　can be used on windows.  Details:
http://monkut.webfactional.com/blog/archive/2010/5/9/creating-pdfs-japnaese-text-using-sphinxpdflatex/

Answer (score 3):

I would use xelatex (available in MikTeX since 2.7) instead of pdflatex and an OpenType Kanji font. The file text.tex consisting of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sazanami Gothic}

\begin{document}
こんにちは 世界
\end{document}
```

compiles with "xelatex text" to a PDF with this text in Sazanami Gothic font.